# Not able to send JSON data using a PUT API request with VBA Macros

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to send some data in JSON format to a server using VBA Macros. I'm using a PUT request to do the same (since this is the only method accepted by the server). However, I get an error that states - {"timestamp":1642010449580,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"java.lang.String cannot be cast to ...}.

The JSON data sample and the code are as below. I'm pretty new to APIs, any help on this issue is much appreciated.

JSON data format sample -

```
[{"Id":"PXX Global012","firstName":"Zoe","lastName":"Hunt","employeeStatus":"","countryCode":"UA","businessunitCode":"PBBCA1234"}, {"Id":"PXX Global012","firstName":"Julie","lastName":"Stan","employeeStatus":"","countryCode":"UA","businessunitCode":"PBBCA5253"}]
```

Code Used -

```
Sub PostJSONData()
  Dim req As New WinHttpRequest
  Dim myUrl As String, userName As String, Password As String, result As String, method As String
  
  myUrl = Configuration.Range("AB2").value
  userName = Configuration.Range("AB5").value
  Password = Configuration.Range("AB6").value
  
  req.Open "PUT", myUrl, False
  
  req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
  req.SetCredentials userName, Password, HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER
  
  req.send ExcelToJSON 'has the JSON data
  result = req.responseText
  
  If req.status <> 200 Then
    MsgBox req.status & " - Error was found while sending the request", vbCritical, "Error while sending API Request"
    Configuration.Range("AD2").value = result
    statusCell.value = req.status
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `cannot be cast to ...` What is the full message ?

Comment: {"timestamp":1642070273529,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.niyo.neorepository.security.AppUser","path":"/config/PXXGlobal/location/v4/updateEmployee"}

Comment: That's the full message, sorry it got cut off earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the issue, looks like a base64 encoding is necessary to send credentials. I've used a function to do the encoding and made some modifications to my original code.

```
Sub PostJSONDatawithEncode()

  Dim req As New WinHttpRequest
  Dim myUrl As String, userName As String, Password As String, result As String, method As String
  
  myUrl = Configuration.Range("AB2").value
  userName = Configuration.Range("AB5").value
  Password = Configuration.Range("AB6").value
  method = Configuration.Range("AB4").value
  
  req.Open method, myUrl, False
  
  req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
  req.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
  req.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + EncodeBase64(userName + ":" + Password)
  
  req.send ExcelToJSON
  result = req.responseText
  Configuration.Range("AD2").value = result
  statusCell.value = req.status
  
  If req.status <> 200 Then
    ' MsgBox req.status & " - Error was found while sending the request", vbCritical, "Error while sending API Request"
    Configuration.Range("AD2").value = result
    statusCell.value = req.status
  End If

End Sub
```